# drag and drop zone with child nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a drag and drop zone with multiple child nodes.

The main element has `dropenter` and `dropleave` events. But if you drag a file inside the main element and over a child node, the `dropleave` is triggered.

How to handle it so the `dropleave` only is called when the dragged element and mouse is outside the main element?

http://jsfiddle.net/4cspcsc4/

```
<div class="drop">
    Drop here
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>

$('.drop').on('dragenter', function(e){
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
})
.on('dragleave', function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
})

.drop {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:#aaa;
}

.drop.highlight {
    border:2px dashed black;
}

.img {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Can you set your fiddle up so the element your want to drag is draggable? Right now it does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS

```
.drop * {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b7pgbhva/