# Dropzone issues - there are spots inside the dropzone that do not work. Dropping files there will open them in browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**File manager = html container that contains a table-like list of files.**

I have made a drop zone as big as the file manager instead of making a designated drop-zone.

## I got inspired by this design:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seXXWRygRkY
I only took the drop zone highlight idea from this video.

[image: drop-zone example]
**If you watch the video you will see that at 0:15 he goes over an element and the drop-zone blinks. This happens with my drop zone in A LOT of places.**

## My current file manager with div hierarchy :

[image: Current file manager]

```
<template>
  <section
    @dragover.prevent="dragOk = true"
    @drop.prevent="addFile"
    @drop.stop.prevent="dragOk = false"
    @dragleave="dragOk = false"
  >
    <div class="top_container">
      <div :class="`mid_container ${dragOk ? 'drag-ok' : ''}`">
        <div class="title">
          <h1>
            File
            <span>Manager</span>
          </h1>
        </div>
        <!-- TODO: File Manager Component -->
        <div v-cloak class="file-manager-container">
          <div class="file-line header">
            <div class="file-name">File name:</div>
            <div class="file-size">Size:</div>
            <div class="action-buttons">Actions:</div>
          </div>
          <div
            :class="`file-line ${file.status ? 'wrong-file' : ''}`"
            v-for="(file, index) in currentFiles"
            :key="index"
          >
            <!-- left  -->
            <div class="file-name">
              {{ file.name }}
              <span v-if="file.status">&nbsp;- {{ file.status }}</span>
            </div>
            <!-- middle  -->
            <div class="file-size">{{ file.size }} kb</div>
            <!-- right -->
            <div class="action-buttons">
              <span>
                <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
              </span>
              <span @click.prevent="currentFiles.splice(index, 1)">
                <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <span v-if="uploading" class="progress-bar">
              <progress :value="progress" max="100">{{progress}}%</progress>
        </span>-->

        <div class="upload-message" v-if="message">
          <div>{{ message }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<style scoped>
.drag-ok {
  background: pink;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 100;
}
</style>
```

## Issue:

If I drag items over some borders or text the dropzone blinks from pink to the default color. If I drop files when the dropzone isn't pink, the browser will open said file.

Here is a fiddle to ilustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/m3wzbyoL/23/

You will have to select a file from your OS, drag it over the area and move it around there and you will see crazy flashes.

Adding `pointer-events: none;` to the `.drop` container will cancel every event from the child element and I do not want this.

If I add `pointer-events: none;` to `.drop .highlight` will make the drag events to not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [drag and drop zone with child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731945/drag-and-drop-zone-with-child-nodes) - you will probably need to do this only when dragging is enabled: `.drag-ok * { pointer-events: none; }`

Comment: @chazsolo `.drag-ok * { pointer-events: none; }` does not work, but `.mid_container { pointer-events:none; }`  does work to an extent. I have some hover elements inside `mid_container` that stopped triggering after I've set `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: Well, you wouldn't want to disable pointer events normally, only on drag.

Comment: @chazsolo Of course not. But setting `.drag-ok * { pointer-events: none; }` makes the flashing even worse.

Comment: Any chance you can make a reproducible example as a snippet within your question? Would be easier to help you debug

Comment: @chazsolo I have been trying for the past hour to do that. I can't do it. I am using Vue CLI and there is no way to put all of that in a simple component on JSfiddle.
￼

￼

Comment: It doesn't need to include Vue, or Vue CLI, or any of that. Just needs to reproduce the issue in plain HTML/JS/CSS

Comment: @chazsolo I finally did it: http://jsfiddle.net/m3wzbyoL/19/. Take a file from OS and move it over the elements and you will see what is happening.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z8caep3v/ check my edits, I believe this is what you're looking for. You don't need to reapply the highlight class on "dragover", and disabling pointer events on child elements prevents the flashing.

Comment: @chazsolo How did you do that ? What is that magic ? Can you post an answer with some detailed information please ? Now I have to figure out how do I apply this to my project.

Comment: @chazsolo I've applied the same fix to my Vue project and it does not work. I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218838/discussion-between-jorje12-and-chazsolo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Ensure you are only toggling the `drag-ok` class on the `dragenter` and `dragleave` events. `dragover` will [fire every few hundred milliseconds and is only for capturing events *as you are dragging*.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dragover_event)
2. Disable `pointer-events` on all the children of the drop-zone target in CSS when the `drag-ok` class is active (not the drop-zone target itself). This will ensure that no other events from children will interfere while dragging.

*Note: code provided as a minimal example, doesn't match code in question exactly..*

```js
$('.drop').on('dragenter', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('drag-ok');
  })
  .on('dragleave', function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('drag-ok');
  })
```

```css
.drop {
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  background: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.drop.drag-ok {
  border: 2px dashed black;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/**
 * The important bit:
 * disable pointer events on all children elements of
 * the drop zone element *only* when the dragenter
 * event has fired (.drag-ok is active)
 */
.drop.drag-ok * {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.img:hover {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div draggable="true">drag me</div>

<div class="drop">
  <span>Drop here</span>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```